# Does the risk neutral pdf that is derived using Litzenberger-Breeden Method correspond to gamma and it's integral correspond to delta?

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options

I derived the pdf using the butterfly prices and the curve looks like gamma of an option at every strike. [image: PDF using butterfly prices] Is that the case or am I missing something to get the pricing of an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many option pricing models, the option price is homogeneous of degree one,
$$C(\lambda S_t,\lambda K)=\lambda C(S_t,K).$$
This property applies to most stochastic volatility and exponential Lévy models. One big exception are local volatility models. Essentially, the condition holds if doubling $S_t$ also doubles $S_T$ (because, for example, $S_T=S_te^{X_{T-t}}$). Then,
\begin{align}
C(\lambda S_t,\lambda K)&=e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t[\max\{\lambda S_T-\lambda K,0\}] \\
&=\lambda e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t[\max\{S_T-K,0\}]\\
&=\lambda C(S_t,K).
\end{align}

Differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ implies
\begin{align*}
S_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t}+K\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}=C.
\end{align*}
This resembles [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler%27s_theorem). Due to monotonicity in strike, we know that $\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}<0$.

Further differentiation with respect to $S_t$ and $K$ implies
\begin{align*}
S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S_t^2}=K^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}.
\end{align*}
Due to convexity in strike, we know that $\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}>0$.

From [Breeden-Litzenberger (1978)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2352653),
\begin{align*}
q(K) &= e^{rT}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}\\
&= e^{rT}\frac{S_t^2}{K^2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \\
&= e^{rT}\frac{S_t^2}{K^2}\Gamma.
\end{align*}
You can thus see that the risk-neutral density is indeed closely linked to gamma. You're right.

Note that the equations $S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S_t^2}=K^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}$ and $S_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t}+K\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}=C$ can be used to calculate gamma and delta in an (almost) model-free fashion, namely
\begin{align}
\Delta &=\frac{C}{S_t}-\frac{K}{S_t}\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}, \\
\Gamma &=\frac{K^2}{S^2_t}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So does that mean I can just use the gamma at every strike to derive the pdf and then integrate that curve to get the delta and prices?

Comment: @vedantbajaj If we knew the right gamma. I added a point about getting gamma from observable option prices, but there is a small modelling assumption that Breeden Litzenberger does not require.